# Configure home page buttons to go to their respective tab

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am working on an application in Xamarin with MVVMCROSS and I came across the following problem:

In my Main View I have 4 buttons and my problem is, when I click on any button I'm directed to the Root, and I always fall from the first View configured in RootViewModel, how to configure my Main buttons so that each one will be directed to their respective View .

--View

```
[MvxRootPresentation (WrapInNavigationController = false)]
public partial class MainView: BaseScrollViewController
{
    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that are not in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        if (ViewModel == null)
        {
          return;
        }

        // Title = "Welcome!";

        / *
         * Binding
         * /
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet <MainView, Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel> ();

        //set.Bind(stkPassword).For("Visibility").To(x => x.stkPasswordVisibility);
        set.Bind (btnNewOrder) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow);
        set.Bind (btnAvailableOrders) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow);
        set.Bind (btnMyTasks) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow);
        set.Bind (btnMyOrders) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow);

        set.Apply ();
   }
}
```

--Model

```
public class MainViewModel: BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;

    private IUserService userService;
    public LoggedUser loggedUser;

    public MainViewModel (IMvxNavigationService navigationService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public IMvxCommand BtnShow
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand (show);
        }
    }
    private void show ()
    {
        ShowViewModel <RootViewModel> ();
    }
 }
```

Today I have configured so that all the buttons, when clicked, go to RootViewModel
--View

```
[MvxRootPresentation (WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public sealed partial class RootView: MvxTabBarViewController <RootViewModel>
{
    private bool _isPresentedFirstTime = true;

    public RootView ()
    {
        //ViewDidLoad ();
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        if (ViewModel! = null && _isPresentedFirstTime)
        {
            _isPresentedFirstTime = false;

            ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModels ();
        }
    }
}
```

--Model

```
public class RootViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    public void ShowInitialViewModels ()
    {
        ShowViewModel <NewOrder2ViewModel> ();
        ShowViewModel <AvailableOrdersViewModel> ();
        ShowViewModel <MyOrdersViewModel> ();
        ShowViewModel <MyTasksViewModel> ();
        ShowViewModel <MoreViewModel> ();
    }
}
```

All pages configured in my RootViewModel are MvxTabPresentation.

**------ Edit**

By clicking a button in the main view, I should direct to your TAB field, for example, if I click on "My Orders", I should be directed to the "My Orders" tab.
As I explained, by clicking on any of my buttons, I'm being directed to the first TAB, because when I click I go to RootViewModel and I can not handle which button I clicked, so I can not direct to their respective TAB

I`m using MvvmCross version 5.0.6

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvqO.png)

Comment: If you are looking for the usage of tabbar ,please refer to here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenusTabs.iOS/Views/TabBarController.cs

Comment: In my case it's a bit different. I have a main screen with four buttons, each one has to point to an item in my tabBar, however the tabBar is set up a a Root page that controls the items on my tab, so in my case it would be MAIN PAGE -> CLICK ON THE BUTTON 2 -> ROOT PAGE -> DISPLAY TAB 2

Comment: Could you add a illustration to describe your requirement, I'm still a little confused..

Comment: @ColeXia I do not know if I could detail enough, but I added more information. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delayed answer.

You can use **CommandParameter** to pass parameter with command on Button click.

**in MainView**

```
set.Bind (btnNewOrder) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow).CommandParameter(1);
set.Bind (btnAvailableOrders) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow).CommandParameter(2);
set.Bind (btnMyTasks) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow).CommandParameter(3);
set.Bind (btnMyOrders) .To (vm => vm.BtnShow).CommandParameter(4);
```

**in MainViewModel**

```
public IMvxCommand BtnShow
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand<int>(show);
    }
}

private void show (int _index)
{
    //here we must wrap int into a model ,because the init method only accept object.
    ShowViewModel <RootViewModel> (new ParametersModel { index = _index});
}
```

**in RootViewModel**

```
public ParametersModel _model;
public void Init(ParametersModel model)
{
    _model = model;
}
```

**ParametersModel**

```
public class ParametersModel 
{
    public int index { get; set; }
}
```

As the code above ,You can get a model with parameter 1 , and you can decide which page should be shown at this time.

#### Update:

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/blob/master/XPlatformMenus/XPlatformMenusTabs.iOS/Views/TabBarController.cs) ,create TabBarController as the sample.

> how to configure my Main buttons so that each one will be directed to their respective View .

Modify the last line code in `ViewDidLoad`

```
SelectedViewController = ViewControllers[ViewModel._model.index];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I'm getting _index as you explained. Now I have a problem, as I learned, when loading RootViewModel I load all my Views `public void ShowInitialViewModels()
  {
   ShowViewModel<NewOrder2ViewModel>();
   ShowViewModel<AvailableOrdersViewModel>();
   ShowViewModel<MyOrdersViewModel>();
   ShowViewModel<MyTasksViewModel>();
   ShowViewModel<MoreViewModel>();
  }`    How do I, upon receiving, for example, _index = 2 displaying my second Tab

Comment: My problem is solved, but when I run it I put the index directly to my Root and I configured the `SelectedViewController = ViewControllers [ViewModel._model.index];` in my **ViewWillAppear**
`public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
{
base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

if (ViewModel! = null && _isPresentedFirstTime)
{
_isPresentedFirstTime = false;

ViewModel.ShowInitialViewModels ();
}

SelectedViewController = ViewControllers [ViewModel._index];
} `
I just used the Index to target the tab I wanted.
Thanks a lot for the help @ColeXia

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa glad to help you . please mark the answer if you have solved your problem